# Customize "Add" button in MultivaluedSection

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I'm trying to change the "Add" button of a MultivaluedSection in Eureka. The current behavior is that when you click on the "Add" button, it creates a new empty cell in the MultivaluedSection.

What I would like to achieve, would be that when a user click on the "Add" button, it shows up a PushRow where the user can choose the initial value of the cell.

I had no luck with any of the two way I tried to get this behavior.

I first tried to create a custom class where I could completely change the MultivaluedSecion behavior :

```
class ExerciseMultivaluedSection : MultivaluedSection {

    override public var addButtonProvider: ((MultivaluedSection) -> ButtonRow) = { _ in
        let button =  ButtonRow {
            $0.title = "MyCustomAddButton"
            $0.cellStyle = .value1
        }.cellUpdate { cell, _ in
            cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
        }

        // Here i would link my button to a function 
        // that would trigger a PushRow, maybe through a segue ?

        return button
    }

    required public init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required public init<S>(_ elements: S) where S : Sequence, S.Element == BaseRow {
        super.init(elements)
    }

    required public init(multivaluedOptions: MultivaluedOptions, header: String, footer: String, _ initializer: (MultivaluedSection) -> Void) {
        super.init(header: header, footer: footer, {section in initializer(section as! ExerciseMultivaluedSection) })
    }
}
```

However, it did not work because of this error : "Cannot override with a stored property 'addButtonProvider'"

Then, I tried to change the addButtonProvider at run time, but it did nothing :

```
    let exerciseSection = MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions:[.Delete,.Reorder,.Insert],header:"Exercises")

    exerciseSection.tag = "exercise"

    exerciseSection.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = {idx in
        let newRow = LabelRow(){row in

            row.value = "TestValue"

            let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "DEL"){action,row,completion in
                completion?(true)
            }
            row.trailingSwipe.actions = [deleteAction]
        }
        return newRow
    }

    exerciseSection.addButtonProvider = {section in
        let addBtn = ButtonRow("Test add"){ row in
            row.title = "Custom add button"
        }

        print("Custom add button" )

        return addBtn
    }
```

Even after that, my add button still shows "Add", and my print function never gets called. Why is that ?

Also, is one of these two ways a good one ? If not, what would be the "correct way" to achieve that ?

I'm using XCode 9.4.1 with iOS 11.4

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to fork and slightly change the Eureka source code, a very few changes will allow you to use a PushRow, or a custom ButtonRow, or any other Row as the AddButtonProvider in a MultiValuedSection.

The few necessary changes are documented in this following GitHub commit which shows the before and after source code changes:
https://github.com/TheCyberMike/Eureka/commit/bfcba0dd04bf0d11cb6ba526235ae4c10c2d73fd

In particular, using a PushRow can be tricky as the add button.  I added information and example code to the Eureka GitHub site in the following issue's comments:
https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/1812
Subsequent comments may be added there by other users of Eureka.

=== From #1812 comment ===

I made a pretty simple change to Eureka in my app's fork to allow any Row to be used as the Add row. It allows the default ButtonRow to be used as-is and handled automatically. But it also allows any other row such as a PushRow to be used as the AddButtonProvider.

In my app, in multiple places, when an end-user presses the add button, I present them a popup list of choices they may add. They choose one, and I add that choice to the MultiValuedSection.

The simple changes are in this forked Eureka commit in my app:
https://github.com/TheCyberMike/Eureka/commit/bfcba0dd04bf0d11cb6ba526235ae4c10c2d73fd

Although I have not tested it in my own app, this change should also support allowing a custom ButtonRow for the MVS. But I think you will need to handle the tableview's .insert in an .onCellSelection in your own code for that custom ButtonRow. The statements you need to do that are in both the commit code above and the example below.

Using a PushRow as an AddButtonProvider is somewhat tricky, since the PushRow invokes a separate view controller to present the list, then returns to the original form's view controller.

1. So you must be sure NOT to rebuild the original form and its MultiValuedSection when viewWillAppear() and viewDidAppear() are called upon returning from the PushRow view controller.
2. Also, the choice itself is made within the PushRow view controller. The PushRow handles preserving that choice back from the PushRow view controller. But the .onChange is invoked while the PushRow view controller is still active. I used a DispatchQueue.main.async closure to handle deferring the tableview .insert call to when the original form's view controller is active.
3. To prevent the PushRow from showing the last choice made in its right-most grayed accessory field, one must nil out its .value. However, that triggers a .onChange too, which if you are not careful can cause an infinite loop situation. I just used a simple if statement to make sure the PushRow's value is not nil to prevent that loop (yes it could also be a guard statement).
4. Be sure to use the [weak self]'s to prevent memory leaks.

Below is an adapted example of usage code from my eContact Collect app (https://github.com/TheCyberMike/eContactCollect-iOS), where things like languages and data entry fields and email accounts are chosen from pre-defined lists.  Again, this code WILL NOT WORK unless the cited source code changes are make.

```
self.mForm = form
form +++ MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Insert, .Delete, .Reorder], header: NSLocalizedString("Shown languages in order to-be-shown", comment:"")) { mvSection in
    mvSection.tag = "mvs_langs"
    mvSection.showInsertIconInAddButton = false
    mvSection.addButtonProvider = { [weak self] section in
        return PushRow(){ row in
            // REMEMBER: CANNOT rebuild the form from viewWillAppear() ... the form must remain intact during the PushRow's view
            // controller life cycle for this to work
            row.title = NSLocalizedString("Select new language to add", comment:"")
            row.tag = "add_new_lang"
            row.selectorTitle = NSLocalizedString("Choose one", comment:"")
            row.options = langOptionsArray
        }.onChange { [weak self] chgRow in
            // PushRow has returned a value selected from the PushRow's view controller;
            // note our context is still within the PushRow's view controller, not the original FormViewController
           if chgRow.value != nil { // this must be present to prevent an infinite loop
               guard let tableView = chgRow.cell.formViewController()?.tableView, let indexPath = chgRow.indexPath else { return }
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   // must dispatch this so the PushRow's SelectorViewController is dismissed first and the UI is back at the main FormViewController
                   // this triggers multivaluedRowToInsertAt() below
                   chgRow.cell.formViewController()?.tableView(tableView, commit: .insert, forRowAt: indexPath)
               }
           }
       }
    } // end of addButtonProvider
    mvSection.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { [weak self] index in
       // a verified-new langRegion code was chosen by the end-user; get it from the PushRow
        let fromPushRow = self!.mForm!.rowBy(tag: "add_new_lang") as! PushRow
        let langRegionCode:String = fromPushRow.value!

        // create a new ButtonRow based upon the new entry
        let newRow = self!.makeLangButtonRow(forLang: langRegionCode)
        fromPushRow.value = nil     // clear out the PushRow's value so this newly chosen item does not remain "selected"
        fromPushRow.reload()        // note this will re-trigger .onChange in the PushRow so must ignore that re-trigger else infinite loop
        return newRow               // self.rowsHaveBeenAdded() will get invoked after this point
    }
}
```